# Is there a way to detect a sound above a certain volume playing through a device and react to it with a command?

Tags: shell-script, audio

I'm doing some scripting for automating a game and I need to click the mouse button and run some bash code every time a loud sound is played in the game. Is this possible with bash?

(Pop OS 19.04)

Comment: I don't know about any ready-made tool, but it's probably not hard to take, say, an existing Pulseaudio example program and add the feature of calling a command when the input exceeds a given level. Yes, you'll need to know how to program.